# How do i find a max value from an attribute with another attribute as an requirement in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this

[image: data]

How do i find max value of MMAX, but the vendor must be an "amdahl"?

Should I make a new data manually?
Use Python, pls..

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html):

```
print(df.groupby('Vendor')['MMAX'].max()['amdahl'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print(max(df.loc[df['Vendor'] == 'amdahl'].MMAX))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df.Vendor == "amdahl"].MMAX.max()
```

---

*The explanation:*

- `df[df.Vendor == "amdahl"]` selects only rows which fulfill the condition in brackets, then
- `.MMAX` returns only the `NMAX` column (as a series), and finally
- `.max()` method returns the maximum of that series values.

---

*Note:*

A more verbose version of the same approach is using the `["colname"]` notations (instead of the abbreviated ones `.colname`):

```
df[df["Vendor"] == "amdahl"]["MMAX"].max()
```